# Interactive change-able pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, charts

as a part of an app that I'm developing, I am looking for an open source pie chart which can be manipulated on mobiles effectively. 
I've found great pie charts such as Flot, jqPlot, HighCharts, etc. however, they only show configured values. While I don't need slice animations of click events, I do need a pie chart with the capability of changing its values from the chart itself, in a way similar to [this](http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/activities/PieChart/).

The point is that I want to force a user to have his values sum up at 100 by favoring a slice and increasing its size at the price of lowering another slice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) is what you're looking for. If you have a look on the bottom right of the home page you'll see interactivity. You can trigger events when an element is clicked that will resize the chart as long as you are willing to do some javascript yourself.

Comment: I fiddled around with it, and it seems it's pretty much similar to the other examples I noted before. I'm still a novice, and a task such as adding drag points at the edge of each slice is something I don't have enough experience for, sadly. That why I was looking for something that was originally oriented in a way that would only need some configuration, like in the example provided above. Thanks a lot, though!

Comment: You'll struggle to find a chart that has interactivity built in already. Charts don't usually need to have their data properties modified by the end user so you won't find a framework like that. If you're not able or willing to learn some javascript then your best bet is to lift the code out of a site like your example where it has been done already.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.